# Django admin download data as csv

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to download data from django admin as .csv file.
I followed tutorial https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2012/02/22/dowloading-csv-file-with-from-django.

**I didn't see download csv option. How can I solve my problem?**

[image]

I am using Python3, migration created.

This is my code

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin


class Stat(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    count = models.IntegerField()


class StatAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('code', 'country', 'ip', 'url', 'count')
    def download_csv(self, request, queryset):
        import csv
        f = open('some.csv', 'wb')
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["code", "country", "ip", "url", "count"])
        for s in queryset:
            writer.writerow([s.code, s.country, s.ip, s.url, s.count])

admin.site.register(Stat, StatAdmin)
```

Comment: Note that the tutorial you reference has moved to: https://www.endpointdev.com/blog/2012/02/dowloading-csv-file-with-from-django/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to add `download_csv` as an action to the `StatAdmin` class.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#adding-actions-to-the-modeladmin

```
def download_csv(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    import csv
    f = open('some.csv', 'wb')
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["code", "country", "ip", "url", "count"])
    for s in queryset:
        writer.writerow([s.code, s.country, s.ip, s.url, s.count])


class StatAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('code', 'country', 'ip', 'url', 'count')
    actions = [download_csv]
```

Comment: I had to use `open('some.csv', 'w')` when using python 3

Answer (score 7):

Solution from @Ben works if you want to save the file locally, moreover there is a little mistake< we should open file as 'w', not 'wb' if we are going to write there some strings.

This solution worked for me (you can past it right in your model.Admin subclass, admin class):

```
def export_as_csv(self, request, queryset):

    meta = self.model._meta
    field_names = [field.name for field in meta.fields]

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={}.csv'.format(meta)
    writer = csv.writer(response)

    writer.writerow(field_names)
    for obj in queryset:
        row = writer.writerow([getattr(obj, field) for field in field_names])

    return response

export_as_csv.short_description = "Export Selected"
```

and then in model.Admin:

```
actions = ("export_as_csv",)
```

[Click here to see the source.](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/export.html)

Moreover there are some libraries that can do saving files in one click: [django-import-export](https://pypi.org/project/django-import-export/#description) for example.

Comment: Works great, very well explained

Answer (score 1):

From Django 3.2 onwards, you also have to register `download_csv` as an "action". See this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/actions/) for the official documentation.