# Django export data to file

Tags: django

I want to export my data of some models to csv/json/txt file.
Is the 'dumpdata' function is the best way?

What is the best option?

I tried:
Python3 manage.py dumpdata myapps > myapps.json
Or copy from my DB tables

Thanks a lot

Comment: You could add a CSV export in your admin panel, that works pretty well. Here is how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72285203/19868773

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found this option as a good one:

```
python3 manage.py dumpdata auth myapp1, myapp2 > mydata.json
```

It saves my data into a JSON file and then can load it with

```
python3 manage.py loaddata mydata.json
```